# how to represent $\int \frac{\arctan \left(x\right)}{x}dx$ as a power series?

Tags: power-series

**I have no idea. I don t even no how to calculate the primitive**
can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Start with the Maclaurin series for arctangent, found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).
2. Divide term-by-term by $x$.
3. Integrate term-by-term.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** You are trying to find an antiderivative for $\frac{1}{x}\arctan x$ and then find a power series for the antiderivative. What about if you try and do these steps in the other order?

Answer (score 2):

> *I don't even no how to calculate the primitive*

Nobody does. :-) It can be proven, using either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), that its antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. In fact, one would need [poly-logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) to do that. But a closed-form expression for its primitive is not needed in order to find its power series: see Vadim's answer.